# search files in all drives using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I work with python and I need a function or library that search for my files in all drives, that I give it just the name of files as <kbd>F3</kbd> in Windows that search on all folders in computer.
windows os , local drives ,, i write a code

```
import os
import win32api
paths = 'D:/'
def dir_list_folder(paths):
    for folderName in os.listdir(paths):
        if (folderName.find('.') == -1):
            folderPath = os.path.join(paths,folderName );
            dir_list_folder(folderPath);
        else:
            print ('Files is :'+ folderName );
```

it give me a good result but some type is give me an error , if i don't need to search in .Zip or .RAR file how i can do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows, you will be better off using the `os.walk` function. `os.walk` returns a generator that recursively walks the source tree. The sample below shows a regular expression search.

```
import os
import re
import win32api

def find_file(root_folder, rex):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(root_folder):
        for f in files:
            result = rex.search(f)
            if result:
                print os.path.join(root, f)
                break # if you want to find only one

def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
    #create a regular expression for the file
    rex = re.compile(file_name)
    for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
        find_file( drive, rex )


find_file_in_all_drives( 'myfile\.doc' )
```

Some notes:

1. I'm using a regular expression for searching the file. For this, I'm compiling the RE ahead of time and then pass it as an argument. Remember to normalize the expression - especially if the file name is coming from a malicious user.
2. `win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings` returns a string with all drivers separated by 0. Split it and then slice out the last element.
3. During the walk, you can remove unwanted folders from 'dirs' such as '.git' or '.cvs'. See `os.walk.__doc__`, for example.
4. To keep the sample short, I did not propagate 'found'. Remove the `break` if you want to print all files. Propagate the `break` to `find_file_in_all_drives` if you want to stop after the first file has been found.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
az = lambda: (chr(i)+":\\" for i in range(ord("A"), ord("Z") + 1))
for drv in az():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drv):
        process_the_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify drives for example for c drive.

```
def findall(directory):
    files=os.listdir(directory)
    for fl in files:
        path=os.path.join(directory,fl)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            findall(path)
        else:
            dosomethingwithfile(path)
    return
```

Basically you traverse file tree. You have to pass drives to this method though as root dir. eg. findall('c:/')

Comment: @specialscope Add a `path = os.path.join(directory, fl)` after the `for` line and replace all `directory+'/'+fl`with `path`.

Comment: it search inside folder good but it search inside files too, should stop if file , not search