# Python search multiple hard drives

Tags: python, search, drive

I'm trying to write a simple script that searches my local drive C: and my two external drives E: and F: for all .docx files and write them to a log. I have the search part down right but can only search one hard drive at a time and can not figure out how to write the results to a .log or .txt file.
Here is my starting code: which does work with  no error

```
import fnmatch
import os
rootPath = 'F:'
pattern = "*.docx"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
    print( os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: For printing to a file rather than the screen, see the docs for print (`file=...`). For searching all drives - you could just loop, I don't think Windows will give you a super-directory containing the drives as directories without sometheng like cygwin or perhaps git-bash.

Comment: why don't you create a list like ```['C:\\','E:\\','F:\\']``` and iterate the rootpath.

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like in my code not sure how to properly insert that - thanks :-)

Comment: Just a personal preference, I'd avoid using the `fnmatch` module for this simple matching task and instead go with `filename.endswith(pattern)`. Mostly for readability's sake.

Comment: So what would your code like if you were trying to search for any .docx file in drives C: E: and F: and write them to a simple .log or .txt file

Comment: Wow thanks Bhansa for your example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fnmatch
import os
drives = ['C:\\','E:\\','F:\\']
pattern = "*.docx"

for rootPath in drives:
    print "Now searching in: ",rootPath
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath) :
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern) :
            print os.path.join(root, filename)
```

write the result in file like this:

```
with open("log.txt","wb") as fs:
    result = "whatever result you are getting"
    fs.write(result)
```

**Update:**

```
import fnmatch
import os
drives = ['C:\\','E:\\','F:\\']
pattern = "*.py"

with open("log.txt","wb") as fs:
    for rootPath in drives:
        print "Now searching in: ",rootPath
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath) :
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern) :
                print os.path.join(root, filename)
                result = os.path.join(root, filename)
                fs.write(result+"\n")
```

Try to write the code yourself then see the solution.

Please ask if you did not understand anything.

Also see this question for other methods: [search files in all drives using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067686/search-files-in-all-drives-using-python)

Comment: Thanks - yes rewriting the code my self and ran it and it works great - but how do I actually get the search results written to the log.txt file

Comment: The log file was created but had your quote "what ever results you are getting"

Comment: that is just to provide an example, write what result you are getting from `os.path.join(root,filename)` in the above code. whatever value you assign to variable `result` will be written to the file.

Comment: I have provided both examples separately so that you can understand and write program from yourself. I want you to understand the problem instead of getting the solution code.

Comment: something like this: result = os.path.join(root, filename)

Comment: Not working - I have only one line written to log.txt file, looks line the lines are getting over written. I think I need to add a \n somewhere just not sure where

Comment: Thanks Bhansa - adding the For statement and the \n did the trick. Thank you for your time I'll spend some time studying the solution

Comment: This is awesome and its working for me. i am trying to make it look for multiple files thought at once is there a way i could do that i have been trying maybe different ways that i thought would work but none of them are working for me

Answer (score 0):

July 28, 2021
I have my Debian, Raspberry Pi, program Thonny, using the above and found that the df terminal command showed my 1 terabyte usb hard drive as
/media/pi/DANDER1TB

df

/dev/sdb1      976727036 215780340 760946696  23% /media/pi/DANDER1TB

so, I just put that in the search program and found my rusty.* file, although it took 8 seconds.

Opie

```
    import fnmatch
    import os
     # change pattern below to search for anythin on the computer
    rootPath = '/media/pi/DANDER1TB'
    pattern = 'rusty.*'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            print( os.path.join(root, filename))
```