# Executing prgram on any PATH

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to execute a program using excel. But it only works on my computer. There are multiple users with different computers. Is there a way for python to search for the file on someone's computer and save that path into xls path code shown below. I tried using `shutil` but I received permission denied error messages for my own directory. The file I'm trying to look for is `Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm`. There are 3 drives: `F:\`, `C:\`, `I:\`. Also if the user saves the excel sheet into multiple areas, how does it distinguish which file that needs to be read.

```
xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application') # Running Excel
xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('I:\TPGeneral\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm')# Reading xlsm file
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath) # Opening file
xlApp.Run('csvfile2')# Running macro---- csvfile2 is the macro name. It is under the "csv" module in the VBA editor
wb.Save()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: I would suggest introducing a config file that the script reads, where the file path is defined. Otherwise as you have stated you have to come up with rules for distinguishing which file needs to be read if the same file exists in multiple places.

Comment: To get the path of the file, you can modify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067686/search-files-in-all-drives-using-python to search just the drives you mentioned and return the full path